# How to use the path suffix in the Metatag page title?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

My articles currently have a [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) page title `[node:title]`. Sometimes this results in duplicate page titles (articles can have the same title), which isn't desirable from a SEO point of view. Therefore, I would like to add a number after `[node:title]` when there already exists an article with the same title.

I use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which adds a suffix to duplicate paths, so this suffix would be perfect. Can I use the path suffix in the Metatag page title? Or is there another possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only token Pathauto provides is `[node:url:args:join-path]`, the generated alias for the node. The suffix originates from, [`pathauto_alias_uniquify(&$alias, $source, $langcode)`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_alias_uniquify/7), which Pathauto doesn't expose in any way; it's generated as needed to ensure the output alias is unique.

Theoretically, you could provide your a custom token that tries to find the value, but it would be error prone; pathauto isn't storing the suffix independently so there's no guarantee that a matched value is actually the suffix generated from Pathauto.

This is more of an editorial problem then a technical one. So a better solution would be to enforce unique titles at an authoring level.

For example, utilizing the [Unique Content Title module](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_node_title) to verify that each node title is unique upon submission.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, in my particular case it really is impossible to enforce unique titles. Even if I do so, a standard title is generated with the Automatic Nodetitles module when no title has been filled in by the user. Any other ideas to cope with this issue?

Comment: I don't know all the particulars of your requirements so it would just be speculative guesses. However, some function is probably evoked for auto nodetitles that you can evoke during a validation handler to compare for uniqueness.